# How do I fix a “System command error” when running “devtools::build_vignettes()” in R？

Tags: r, devtools

I am developing a package. The “.Rmd” files already exist in the “./vignettes” folder in the root directory of the package. I want to automatically create “.html” and “.pdf” documents into./inst/doc, so run the following code：

```
   library("devtools") 
   build_vignettes
```

Then Errors occurred：

> Building PhosMap vignettes    Error in (function (command = NULL,
>   args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : System command error
>   Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(),
>   error_on_status = TRUE,  : System command error

My R version is 3.6.0.

Comment: Try the suggestions [here](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2031).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get similar issue when run `devtools::build_vignettes()`.

In my case reason of this issue was that I made a mistake in `namespace` in the names of exported functions.

So try to verify the package by `devtools::check()`

But also you can try next:

1. Check you PATH, there must be a path to rtools: `C:\Rtools\bin\;` and `C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\`.
2. Set system environment variables BINPREF `"C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/"`.

Comment: Thanks, there is something wrong with my NAMESPACE file as you said. However, after correction, another warning occurs,` > build_vignettes()
Building PhosMap vignettes
--- re-building 'introduction_of_PhosMap.Rmd' using rmarkdown
--- finished re-building 'introduction_of_PhosMap.Rmd'

Warning: `recursive` is deprecated, please use `recurse` instead
Moving introduction_of_PhosMap.html, introduction_of_PhosMap.R to doc/
Copying introduction_of_PhosMap.Rmd to doc/
Warning: `recursive` is deprecated, please use `recurse` instead
Building vignette index`

Comment: Hi, `Warning: recursive is deprecated, please use recurse` is  just warning. Update your devtools to ‘2.0.2.9000’ version by `devtools::install_github("r-lib/devtools")` and rerun `devtools::build_vignettes()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, I can build vignettes smoothly now.